# npm package makes codesandbox show blank screen

Tags: reactjs, npm, codesandbox

for the first time, I made a react library to handle infinite scroll for window and element.
the package works with no problem when I create a react app and install the package on it.
but in code sandbox when I add the package to the dependencies, it goes blank and shows nothing till I remove the package

here is the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snp-infinite-scroller

here is a project that used it with no problem:

source: https://github.com/rezaerami/react-snp-infinite-scroller-docs

demo: https://rezaerami.github.io/docs-react-snp-infinite-scroller/

here is a sample code sandbox react application with no changes only added the package to dependencies:

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-meadow-tuxjo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that maybe because of missing `main` point `and/or`.git`from repository URL inside your`package.json`

> Provide responses for the required fields (name and version), as well as the main field:

- name: The name of your module.
- version: The initial module version. We recommend following semantic versioning guidelines and starting with 1.0.0.
- main: The name of the file that will be loaded when your module is required by another application. The default name is index.js. [Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules)

Try to add:

```
"main": "index.js,
"repository": {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "https://github.com/rezaerami/react-snp-infinite-scroller.git"
},
```

Also, I'd recommend to add a `description`, `author`, `license`, `tags`, `keywords` blocks that will help people find your package.

See all [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json.html) handling.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I added the main and other fields and published it again but nothing happened

Comment: Maybe that caused by `@testing-library` packages? try to remove them all, they unrelated anyway.

Comment: removed all unused packages as you said, it's working now, thanks man